# Make Cartoon-like car headlight light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, shaders, lighting

I want to make the light appear on the floor in a defined oval shape, without any scattering but be translucent anyway. kind of like this picture, but appearing only on the ground maybe. This is part of an animation of the car going around a small world.

Here is the file. Thank you in advance!!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you making this in 2D or 3D? If 3D, you can use a spot light and position it in the headlight of the car, keyframing it's position. You also wouldn't need to use nodes for that.
[image]
If 2D, and you want to have it be casting a yellow tint on the background, then you can make the light a yellow plane and decrease the alpha transparency value.